# javascript sum user defined numbers

Tags: javascript, variables, numbers, sum, user-defined

```
<script language="Javascript">
function monthlyPayment (form) {
    var down = form.dPayment.value;
    var trade = form.tradeIn.value;
    var totalDown = down + trade;

alert ("Total down is " + totalDown);
}
</script>
```

This is a beginner question as I'm new to Javascript... but I am just trying to make a mock up of a feature I'm trying to implement on my website.

I have a form with two user definable variables for 'Down Payment' and 'Trade-In'. Everything in the code works, except for when it "add's" the numbers (such as $100 + $200), it doesn't output $300, but instead $100200. When I change the sign to multiplication it outputs a correct value.

What am I missing? Is there some .sum or .math code I need to implement? Or is my entire script screwed?

Thank you all for your time and help.

Comment: Use `parseInt` or `parseFloat` or `Number` or `+` on the value taken from DOM to convert it to Numer

Comment: form values are STRINGS. if you want them to be treated as numbers, you'll have to convert them to numbers first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very common mistake people new with javascript make.
the `+` sign is used to concatenate in javascript, which explains your result is 100200 when you try. What you give him is string, so he just concatenates the two.

use the `Number()` function to make sure their types become "Number" so your addition will work correctly.

```
var totalDown = Number(down) + Number(trade);
```